# Using JSDoc to set an index signature on an ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc, es6-class, index-signature

In Typescript, you'd just do this:

```
class Test {
  [key: string]: whatever
}
```

Which allows you to access computed property names like so...

```js
class Test {
  getProp(key) {
    return this[key]
  }
}
```

... without receiving `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Test' has no index signature.`

I can't figure out how to accomplish the equivalent with JSDoc. Anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: Yep, so with a normal object you'd just do: 
`/** @type {{ [key: string]: string }} */`
`const obj = { key: 'string' }`

Comment: Nah, it definitely falls under more obscure usage. I thought https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html would cover it but no dice.

Comment: Note: I'm using JSDoc not primarily for documentation but for type-checking in JS

Comment: Why do you need to store or access dynamic property names on the class

Comment: Scenario: I pass in a parameter to the constructor that's an object with many keys/values. I want to then assign those properties directly to the class so that the end-user doesn't have to do `Test.object.property` and can simply do `Test.property`.

Answer (score 2):

For a single method, it's possible to do this with the `@this` tag:

```
class Test {
    /**
     * @this {{[k: string]: string}}
     * @param {string} key
     */
    getProp(key) {
        return this[key]
    }
}
```

Doing it for the entire class isn't yet supported. There is an open feature request ([TypeScript#48096](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48096)) which is currently in the TS 4.7.1 milestone. However, given the `Needs Proposal` label, somebody needs to come up with a proposed JSDoc tag + syntax, or it will likely end up being pushed off that milestone.

Comment: This looks pretty canonical to me. Thanks for pointing us to ward an official source.